# Libcurl not usable on mac os x

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, curl

I'm running the configure command to install a particular software package, but it fails when it reaches it's libcurl requirement.

This is the output it gives:

```
checking for the version of libcurl... 7.34.0
checking for libcurl >= version 7.15.2... yes
checking whether libcurl is usable... no
configure: error: Missing required libcurl >= 7.15.2
```

So, I have version 7.34 installed, which is greater than the required 7.15.2 - but for some reason it is not usable.. (line 3).

curl --version outputs the following:

```
> curl --version
curl 7.34.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0) libcurl/7.34.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1e zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.26
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP
```

Any idea of what's going on here?

Comment: check config.log after the run failed, it will show you the test configure tried that failed...

Comment: One option is to install libcurl using homebrew (http://brew.sh/) or macports (http://macports.org/), then link against newer version of libcurl. OS/X ships quite old libcurl, so this might actually be only option.