# MAMP php and libcurl

Tags: php, curl, mamp

I installed MAMP 4.0.6 and it works fine, but I want to use symfony and I need to use php in command line. But when I use it, I have :

```
php -v

dyld: Library not loaded: /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libcurl.4.dylib

Referenced from: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.12/bin/php

Reason: Incompatible library version: php requires version 9.0.0 or later, but libcurl.4.dylib provides version 7.0.0
```

I just reinstall the 7.50.3 with this tutorial : http://dev.soup.io/post/56438473/If-youre-using-MAMP-and-doing-something

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

## Install Newer `libcurl` Or Older MAMP.

A comment on [this question](https://superuser.com/q/708103/676912) indicates that `libcurl.dylib` is a macOS component, and if you want a newer version of you'll need to resort to [macports.org](http://macports.org/) or [brew.sh](http://brew.sh/).

The other option is to install an older version of MAMP that works with the older version of `libcurl`.